# Get matching or next closest larger value in an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I find or search for the next closest larger number in an array?

For example, let's assume the following is my array

```
array( 10, 8, 6, 12, 4, 20 )
```

when I search for `9`, it should give me `10` from the above array

if I search for `13` it should give me `20`

if I search for `5` it should give me `6`

and so on

Comment: This is a simple `foreach` loop. Show us your attempt, and explain what the problem is. Edit: your profile lists extensive experience that should certainly cover this. I wonder why you need to ask.

Comment: Loop and set the lowest value. Continue iterating and check if next value is lower than current lowest.

Comment: Sort, remove all value below yours then take the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tradeoff in compute in sorting versus iterating over the whole thing. I'm not a compsci major and if I had to eliminate microseconds somewhere I'd benchmark this but it works fine.

```php
function closest($array, $number)
{
    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a >= $number) return $a;
    }
    return end($array);
}

$array = array( 10, 8, 6, 12, 4, 20 );

echo closest($array, 9); // 10
echo closest($array, 13); // 20
echo closest($array, 5); // 6
```

Comment: Worked great. The only slight issue is, when you enter a number larger than any of the elements in the array it will pick the next least number.

Comment: That sounds correct to me. If you do `closest($array, 25)` you'll get `20` which is correct as it's the closest value in the array.

Comment: Please don't respond to questions with no code or apparent effort on the part of the asker. They posted a spec and you did their work/homework for them.

Answer (score 0):

Also figured out a new way of solving it Great to @Daniel Tharp for the great answer. What I did was to loop through each element of an array, and picked all the numbers that are bigger than the search then pushed them into a fresh new array. Finally, I used PHP `min` to get the least number from the newly created array.

Be careful when using `min` as it can trigger an error if no match was found in an array. See the solution below.

```
function wpccb_get_next_closest_large_number( $search, $array ){
  $array_of_all_larger_numbers = array();
  foreach( $array as $value ){
    if( $search < $value ){
        array_push( $array_of_all_larger_numbers, $value );
    }
  }
  
  if( count( $array_of_all_larger_numbers ) == 0 ){
    return 0;
  }
  
  return min( $array_of_all_larger_numbers );
}
```